# Relying on nhibernate's second level cache vs pushing objects into asp.net session

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, second-level-cache

I have some big entities which are frequently accessed in the same session. For example, in my application there is a reporting page which consist of dynamically generated chart images. For each chart image on this page, the client makes requests to corresponding controller and the controller generates images using some entities. 
I can either use asp.net's session dictionary for "caching" those entities or rely on nhibernate's second level cache support with using cached queries for example.

What is your opinion?

By the way I will use shared hosting, is nhibernate's second level cache hosting friendly?

Thanks.

Comment: I would write the images out to disk then reference them directly as the image src.

Comment: My question's scope not limitied with this particular issue. And i wouldn't want to manage lifecylce of those generated image files in the hosting.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use NHibernate's cache. If user makes distinct request to get each entity one by one then you probably should use different NHibernate ISession implementations to get them (bacause of session per web request strategy).

Also when using Nhibernate cache you won't have troubles with concurrency issues - it will handle them for you.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware of caching an entity (from the session you loaded it from) in a static variable, that is then accessed by another session (eg, pulled from the cache system you made).

Entity instances are tied to a Session remember, so you shouldn't mix and match instances across Session boundaries.

I've solved this before by creating a light version of the class (that is not NH Session aware) and caching that basic class instead.

Alternatively, use the 2nd level cache, which doesn't have this problem.